# DRCSIM: model.sdf needs to be updated

Tags: drcsim, sdformat

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

drc_robot model.sdf needs to be updated to match the current drc_skeleton.cfg
mtorso, l_uglut, l_lglut, l_talus, r_uglut, r_lglut, r_talus moi are out of date

```
For example:
    struct mtorso
            index   = 2
            parent_link = ltorso
            parent_kin_dof = back.mby
            mass   = 0.55
            moi_xx = 0.00045418082817329496
            moi_xy = -6.1076431791225316e-05
            moi_xz = 3.9400936229127748e-05
            moi_yy = 0.00048328164990909611
            moi_yz = 5.2746296530367189e-05
            moi_zz = 0.00044421486752431325
            com_x  = -0.0081626617
            com_y  = -0.013124485
            com_z  = 0.03059743
```

vs.
link name="mtorso"
inertia ixx="0.01" ixy="0" ixz="0" iyy="0.01" iyz="0" izz="0.01"

Some joints like back_mby are also out of date.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/404/drcsim:-model.sdf-needs-to-be-updated/) by [cga](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/66/cga/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 223 on 2012-12-04

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

I believe this has been addressed by [issue #36](https://bitbucket.org/osrf/drcsim/issue/36/inertia-of-certain-links-is-very-large) and [pull request #37](https://bitbucket.org/osrf/drcsim/pull-request/37/more-fixes-to-issue-36/diff).  Please let me know if I missed something.

Thanks,
John

---

Originally posted by [hsu](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/6/hsu/) with karma: 1873 on 2012-12-04

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gerkey](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/74/gerkey/) on 2013-01-11**:
The values were corrected as of drcsim 1.3.1 (and possibly earlier).